# Java 8 Optional orElse orElseThrow inconsistent

Tags: java, java-8, option-type

If a is Optional[123] and b is Optional[empty].

```
a.orElse(b.orElseThrow(() -> new UnexpectedInternalException(
                    "Error")))
```

Why does it throw?

Comment: What did you expect it to do? The `orElseThrow()` method is explicity designed to throw if your `Optional` is absent...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`orElse()` is a method, and before that method is executed, its arguments are evaluated. In this case the evaluation of the argument (`b.orElseThrow(() -> new UnexpectedInternalException("Error"))`) throws an exception.

Answer (score 5):

Because parameters are evaluated first. This has nothing to do with Optional...